# How to change pixel value of RGB image in Python Program

Tags: image, python-2.7, edit, pixel

I want to change the pixels values in the following image using Python Program:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AreI2.jpg)

Actually, I'm new in Python. I have tried with following code, but it shows error :

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
im=im.convert('RGB')
width, height = im.size
pixel_values = list(im.getdata())
#print "widht=",width
#print "height=",height
#print pixel_values
for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            r,g,b = im.getpixel((i,j))
            if r>=128:
                r=255,g=0,b=0
            elif g>=128:
                r=0,g=255,b=0
            elif b>=128:
                r=0,g=0,b=255
            pixels[i,j] = (r,g,b)
im.save('myimage.jpg')
```

How can I make change of the pixels?